# ACH Stripe Bank Account Verification

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller, stripe-payments

I am trying to verify a bank account with Stripe. The closest language in the Stripe documentation is Node.js so my code is a little different but the problem that there's not "customers" object on the stripe object created from stripe.js.

Their code (https://stripe.com/docs/ach#manually-collecting-and-verifying-bank-accounts):

```
// Set your secret key: remember to change this to your live secret key in production
// See your keys here: https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys
var stripe = require("stripe")("my_secret_key");

var data = {amounts: [32,45]}
stripe.customers.verifySource(
  'customer_id',
  'bank_account_id',
  {
    amounts: [32, 45]
  },
  function(err, bankAccount) {

});
```

My code:

```
<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
<script>
    $('input').on('keydown', function (e) {
        if (e.which == 13) {
            $('#VerificationAmounts').submit();
        }
    });

    $('#VerificationAmounts').submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var stripe = Stripe("@publishKey");

        var data = { amounts: [$('#Amount1').val(), $('#Amount2').val()] }
        debugger;
        stripe.customers.verifySource(
          '@customerId',
          '@bankAccount.Id',
          data,
          function (err, bankAccount) {

          });
    });
</script>
```

Error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'verifySource' of undefined
```

Does anyone know of a way to make the "customers" object populate on the stripe object?

Comment: You're trying to perform server side actions using a client side library, it's not going to work.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction @Alex!

Answer (score 1):

Per @Alex's comment, I was trying to use the stripe.js to verify the bank account but instead I should have been using the Stripe API. Since I'm using `C# MVC` I needed to pass the micro-payment amounts the customer provided to my Controller and call the `Verfiy` method of the `Stripe.net` class `BankAccountService` per documentation: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-dotnet.